# Continously running Celery Task in Django

Tags: django, apache-kafka, celery, celeryd

I've a Django app which should constantly listen for messages from Kafka and then send them via WebSocket to client. Problem is how to setup constant listener. For future scalability we decided to bring Celery in project to manage these issues with scaling.

My task actually look like:

```
class ConsumerTask(Task):
    name = 'consume_messages'

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        consumer = get_kafka_consumer(settings.KAFKA_URL,
                                      settings.FAULT_MESSAGES_KAFKA_TOPIC,
                                      'consumer_messages_group')
        logger.info("Kafka's consumer has been started")

        while True:
            messages = consumer.poll()
            for _, messages in messages.items():
                messages, messages_count = self.get_message(messages)
                if messages_count > 0:
                    messages = save_to_db()
                    send_via_websocket_messages(messages)
```

It properly saves and sends messages via WS, but problems comes from infinite loop in task.
For some reason (probably task timeout constraint) task pop out if queue and never runs again.
I am not sure that daemonizing celery workers will solve this problem.
Could you please provide some strategies now organize "Constantly running part" of this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use case does **not** fit celery tasks well. Celery tasks should not be long running processes. You need to put tasks in the broker queue which also makes no sense in your setup.

Think about your while-True-loop rather as a **celery worker**. The worker is supposed to run constantly and it's also the process you need to scale up when handling more tasks.

Write a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/) that uses your while-True-loop and use the kind of scaling you would use to scale celery workers to run multiple instances of that managemement command.

Use process management tools for scaling up processes like [honcho](https://pypi.org/project/honcho/) or [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

Comment: can you provide any resources/links/reasons to why celery tasks should not be long running processes? I see people on stackoverflow saying they have celery setup for tasks that take as long as 80 hours. 

I want to implement a system with very long running tasks and have to choose something..

Comment: By "long running processes" I mean servers (ie the code in the question). If your celery and system setup can support 80 hours for a single task execution, go for it. Servers don't complete a task execution, they are stopped or restarted which is not what celery tasks are designed to do.